# Setting connection in n-tier c# layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to setup my database in my new project with a database, however I keep getting this issue:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll
```

I created an empty 4.5 project using web api folder. then I added 3 class library, BO (business ojbect), BLL (business logic), and DAL (data access layer).

First the main app has web.config with a connection string like this

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Quantico;Integrated Security=True" providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In my BO library I have 2 class base, and gender

Base

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Boolean isValid { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
    public int createdID { get; set; }
    /*public Person createdPerson { get; set; }*/
    public DateTime updatedOn { get; set; }
    public int updatedID { get; set; }
    /*public Person updatedPerson { get; set; }*/
}
```

Gender

```
public class Gender : Base
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In my dal I have 2 class GenderDAL and Appcontext

```
AppContext is like this
    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppContext() : base("ConnString")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Gender> Gender { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().ToTable("Gender");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(255);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.createdID).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.createdOn).IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

GenderDAL is as follow

```
    public class GenderDAL : AppContext
    {
        private AppContext db = null;

        public GenderDAL()
        {
            db = new GenderDAL();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Gender> GetGenders()
        {
            return db.Gender.ToList<Gender>();
        }
    }
```

The issue occurs at base(connstring) and my controller is like this

```
public class GenderController : ApiController
{
    private GenderBLL db = null;

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Gender> Genders()
    {
        db = new GenderBLL();
        return db.GetGenders();
    }
}
```

and my business logic is not much at this stage but its like this

```
public class GenderBLL
{
    private GenderDAL db = null;

    #region constructor
    public GenderBLL()
    {
        db = new GenderDAL();
    }
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<Gender> GetGenders()
    {
        return db.GetGenders();
    }
}
```

If I look at my server explorer, i can see under dataconnection that I am connected to the database, however no table exist. I believe that is my issues, and i am not sure how to either populate it, or what step did I miss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the connection string. Looking at your `GenderDAL` class:

```
public class GenderDAL : AppContext
{
    private AppContext db = null;

    public GenderDAL()
    {
        db = new GenderDAL();
    }
    //..
```

Your `GenderDAL` class inherits from `AppContext`, and inside your constructor you are creating a `new GenderDAL()` (which recursively creates another nested `GenderDAL`, and so on, infinitely). This causes infinite recursion until the stack goes full and the framework throws a `StackOverflowException`.

I do not see any valid reasons for inheriting your DAL objects from `AppContext` and I strongly suggest you to remove such inheritance.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaa.  I didn't see that one!  I agree, remove the inheritance.

Comment: This cause me a new issues, so what I did is removed, : Appcontext and now i am getting this 

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name '.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Check this link if you are using local db version 13 http://www.michael-whelan.net/sql-server-localdb-2014-connection-string/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().ToTable("Gender");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(255);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.createdID).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(x => x.createdOn).IsRequired();

     /* optional addition */
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

PS

You can get a "seed data" example from here:

https://github.com/ProgrammingAspNetMvcBook/CodeExamples/tree/master/Ebuy.Common/DataAccess

Also check your connection string and config.

Example (based on Northwind)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer\Instance;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name='Northwindy'"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: unfortunotly when I go to http://localhost:53069/api/gender I still received the unhandled exception of type system.stack.overflowexception occurred in system.core.dll. The issue occurs here public AppContext() : base("ConnString")